# Getting started with int8 arithmetic using dp4a()

Tags: cuda, mex

I am trying to use 8 bit integer intrinsics as described in this post: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/mixed-precision-programming-cuda-8/

Inside a kernel I simply try to call

```
D = __dp4a(A, B, C);
```

and this results in compiler error

> error: identifier "__dp4a" is undefined

Next I tried adding the header file

```
#include <sm_61_intrinsics.h>
```

but it had no effect. Lastly, I added this line:

```
__device__ int __dp4a(char4 srcA, char4 srcB, int c);
```

and then I get another compiler error:

> Error using **mex**
>
> ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_Z6__dp4a5char4S_i'

I have CUDA v8.0 running on a GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, compute capability 6.1, and it is supposed to support dp4a. Am I missing something? Could this be a Mex/Matlab/Visual Studio  problem?

Comment: Are you compiling for an architecture which supports those intrinsics?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to set the architecture. I have just tried compiling with mexcuda '-LC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64 --gpu-architecture=compute_61 --gpu-code=compute_61' -lcurand mysource.cu This did not fix the error

Comment: I don't see any trouble with using CUDA 8 and `__dp4a` directly (i.e. without matlab/mex).  See [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/979016/unable-to-reach-full-throughput-on-titan-x-pascal-for-__dp4a/) for example.  I would assume there is something going on with your matlab version or with mex in general, but its not obvious to me what it is.  You might want to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is a Matlab 2017a and/or Visual Studio 2012 problem. In my case I fixed it by going to the

> C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2017a\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\src\mex\win64\nvcc_msvcpp2012.xml

file, where the compiler settings are, and modifying this line:

> ARCHFLAGS="-gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 
>   -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61 $NVCC_FLAGS"

which I copied from [this guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pascal-compatibility-guide/index.html). The default settings only had sm_60 as the highest architecture, and we need sm_61 for __dp4a() to work.